# tcolorbox in separate environment picking up style values from another tcolorbox

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, pandoc

I have two environments, tip, and codeheading, each with their own tcolorboxes, like so:

```
    \newenvironment{tip}
        {\tcolorbox[colback=tip-green-background, frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, enlarge bottom by=0.3cm, enhanced jigsaw, borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{tip-green-border}, title={Tip \\[1mm]}, colbacktitle={tip-green-border}, coltitle={tip-green-text}, coltext={tip-green-text}, fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}]}
        {\endtcolorbox}
```

```
    \newenvironment{codeheading}[1]
        {\tcolorbox[colback=code-filename-background, every box, sharp corners=south, enlarge bottom by=-2.5mm, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, enhanced jigsaw, title={#1}, colbacktitle={black}, coltitle={white}, fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}]}
        {\endtcolorbox}
```

I'm noticing that the `tip` environment tcolorbox is picking up stylistic values that have been defined in the `codeheading` environment.

For example, `codeheading` has `sharp corners=south`, which `tip` then also has. If I change this value from south to north, tip's corners also change.

Why would two tcolorboxes be picking up each other's style values? It's like after they colorboxes are used on the page, each one starts picking up the other's style. They get..confused?

I'm using Pandoc, too.

```
---
geometry: margin=3cm
mainfont: SF Pro Display
mainfontoptions: BoldFont=SF Pro Display Bold
monofont: Fira Code
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \spacing{1.25}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Blah blah blah}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \definecolor{tip-green-text}{HTML}{165c26}
    \definecolor{tip-green-background}{HTML}{dcffe4}
    \definecolor{tip-green-border}{HTML}{96f1b5}
    \definecolor{code-filename-background}{HTML}{161621}
    \newenvironment{tip}
        {\tcolorbox[colback=tip-green-background, frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, enlarge bottom by=0.3cm, enhanced jigsaw, borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{tip-green-border}, title={Tip \\[1mm]}, colbacktitle={tip-green-border}, coltitle={tip-green-text}, coltext={tip-green-text}, fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}]}
        {\endtcolorbox}
    \newenvironment{codeheading}[1]
        {\tcolorbox[colback=code-filename-background, every box, sharp corners=south, enlarge bottom by=-2.5mm, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, enhanced jigsaw, title={#1}, colbacktitle={black}, coltitle={white}, fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}]}
        {\endtcolorbox}
     \newcommand{\codesnippet}[1]{\singlespacing \small \begin{codeheading}{#1} \end{codeheading}} 
---

# Usage
This is dummy text

\codesnippet{App.js}
console.log('test');

\bigbreak

\begin{tip}
To be or not to be, that is the question!
\end{tip}

# Heading 2

Some more text...

\codesnippet{Latex.js}
console.log('Hello!')
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please note that `tcolorbox` has a command`\newtcolorbox` specifically for that. And please provide us with a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: make a complete example for tests.

Comment: @marmot I've edited my answer to include the entire code snippet and updated the screenshots to show the output.

Comment: a code snippet is not a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\newtcolorbox`, which is made for this, the issue does not arise. (You could also work with groups but I would prefer the built-in solution.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.25}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Blah blah blah}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{tip-green-text}{HTML}{165c26}
\definecolor{tip-green-background}{HTML}{dcffe4}
\definecolor{tip-green-border}{HTML}{96f1b5}
\definecolor{code-filename-background}{HTML}{161621}
\newtcolorbox{tip}{colback=tip-green-background, 
frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, 
enlarge bottom by=0.3cm, enhanced jigsaw, 
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{tip-green-border}, 
title={Tip \\[1mm]}, colbacktitle={tip-green-border}, 
coltitle={tip-green-text}, coltext={tip-green-text}, 
fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}}
\newtcolorbox{codeheading}[1]{colback=code-filename-background, every box, sharp corners=south, enlarge bottom by=-2.5mm, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, enhanced jigsaw, title={#1}, colbacktitle={black}, coltitle={white},
fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}}
\newcommand{\codesnippet}[1]{\singlespacing \small \begin{codeheading}{#1} 
\end{codeheading}} 
\begin{document}
\# Usage
This is dummy text

\codesnippet{App.js}
console.log('test');

\bigbreak

\begin{tip}
To be or not to be, that is the question!
\end{tip}

\# Heading 2

Some more text\dots

\codesnippet{Latex.js}
console.log('Hello!')
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that in its present form your command `\codesnippet` does not make too much sense. Something like the following may be more useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.25}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Blah blah blah}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{tip-green-text}{HTML}{165c26}
\definecolor{tip-green-background}{HTML}{dcffe4}
\definecolor{tip-green-border}{HTML}{96f1b5}
\definecolor{code-filename-background}{HTML}{161621}
\newtcolorbox{tip}{colback=tip-green-background, 
frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, 
enlarge bottom by=0.3cm, enhanced jigsaw, 
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{tip-green-border}, 
title={Tip \\[1mm]}, colbacktitle={tip-green-border}, 
coltitle={tip-green-text}, coltext={tip-green-text}, 
fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}}
\newtcolorbox{codeheading}[1]{colback=code-filename-background, 
every box, sharp corners=south, enlarge bottom by=-2.5mm,
boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable, enhanced jigsaw, 
 coltext={tip-green-text}, 
title={#1\\[1mm]}, colbacktitle={black}, coltitle={white}, 
fonttitle={\small\bfseries}, attach title to upper={}}
\newcommand{\codesnippet}[1]{\singlespacing \small \begin{codeheading}{#1} 
\end{codeheading}} 
\begin{document}
\# Usage
This is dummy text

\begin{codeheading}{App.js}
console.log('test');
\end{codeheading}

\bigbreak

\begin{tip}
To be or not to be, that is the question!
\end{tip}

\# Heading 2

Some more text\dots

\begin{codeheading}{Latex.js}
console.log('Hello!')
\end{codeheading}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that `tcolorbox` supports listings.

Comment: +1. Also notice that you can factor out common styles with `\tcbset{common/.style={boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, breakable,},}` and then use it as `\newtcolorbox{tip}{common, ...`

Comment: I'm not able to compile this successfully. I'm using pandoc and I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` I've debugged it and I only get this error when using a `newtcolorbox` with parameters.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks!!

Comment: @jcrowson Frankly, I doubt it, but I also do not use `pandoc`. You can use your approach and then add `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, ` \newenvironment{tip}
        {\begingroup\tcolorbox[....}{\endtcolorbox\endgroup}`. And in future add such relevant information to your questions, otherwise you frustrate everyone.

Comment: @marmot I tried the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` syntax and that worked. There must be a bug in Pandoc's parser. Thanks!